# Why does AWS EC2 Only offer python 3.7.2 installation with yum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've started an EC2 instance and have to use yum to install python. In order to see all available versions of Python 3 I ran this command: `sudo yum list | grep python3` and I get back this list:

```
python3.x86_64                         3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-Cython.x86_64                  0.27.3-2.amzn2.0.2             amzn2-core
python3-debug.x86_64                   3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-devel.x86_64                   3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-libs.i686                      3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-libs.x86_64                    3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-lit.noarch                     0.7.1-1.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-pip.noarch                     9.0.3-1.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-rpm-macros.noarch              3-23.amzn2                     amzn2-core
python3-setuptools.noarch              38.4.0-3.amzn2.0.6             amzn2-core
python3-test.x86_64                    3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-tkinter.x86_64                 3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-tools.x86_64                   3.7.2-4.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-wheel.noarch                   0.30.0a0-9.amzn2.0.3           amzn2-core
```

It looks like there are no distributions of Python 3.6 in yum on ec2 instances. Does anyone know why this is? I know you can use `wget`, but I don't understand why Amazon would make you jump through so many more hoops to get 3.6.

Comment: Why would they offer more than that? In any case, unless Amazon has published their reasoning somewhere or an employee cares to answer this requires us to speculate about why a private corporation made a particular decision. That's not on-topic here.

Comment: This is annoying me as well. I want to use `rpmconf` from EPEL, but it requires python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I think yum only shows the latest version by default. I don't have a yum box handy to test this on, but I found [this resource](https://www.shellhacks.com/yum-install-specific-version-of-package/). It looks like you can show alternate versions with:

```
yum list python3 --showduplicates
```

You can then install a specific version with (assuming the version info is just "3.6"):

```
sudo yum install python3-3.6
```

more generally `sudo yum install <package_name>-<version>`.